# Probability of an event happening in a given time window

Tags: probability

I am not an mathematician so forgive me if my terminology is incorrect. I believe this question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439281/probability-of-an-event-happening-n-or-more-times) but I am not sure.

Imagine there is a process that happens once per second and takes 17 ms to finish. That is at t = 0 the process starts and runs for 17 ms, then the process is stopped for 0.983 s, then at t = 1 the process starts again, and so on.

Now I randomly select an instant of time, i.e. 0.23 s, 0.550203 s, 0.9999 s, from every second and do so for, say, 8 hours (28800 selections).

What is the probability that I would have selected, say 1000, instants that coincide with the running process?

I have a feeling that I am making this more complicated than I have to.

The probability that a single selection occurs during the running process is 17 ms / 1 s = 0.017.

That's about as far as I've got.

Edit: really what I want to know is the probability that I select *at least* 1000 instants that coincide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that each time is chosen independently of the others, then the random variable that describes the number of selections that coincide with the running process follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,%2Fone%20(with%20probability%20p)).

In your example, if we want *exactly* $1000$ coincidences, the probability will be:
$$P= {28800 \choose 1000}(0.017)^{1000}(1-0.017)^{27800}.$$

Why? We perform $28800$ selections, and we must choose $1000$ to be our "successes" trials, what can be made of $28800 \choose 1000$ ways. If we want exactly $1000$ coincidences, those $1000$ selections must coincide, and this happens with probability $(0.017)^{1000}$ AND the other selections must NOT coincide, and this happens with probability $(1-0.017)^{27800}$.

Of course, calculate this probability exaclty is difficult. In this case, since the probability of success is small and the number of trials is large, we can [approximate the Binomial Distribution by a Normal one.](https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/statistics/normal-approximations#:%7E:text=The%20normal%20distribution%20can%20be,approximately%20N(np%2C%20npq))

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. I guess the difficulty in computing the answer lies in the difficulty of the factorial calculation?

Comment: Yes. Note that, since the number trials is large, the probability of exactly $1000$ successes is pratically $0$. It's most interesting to compute things like "at most" $1000$ successes and the like. You can use this online calculator to help you https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx